# What are the counterarguments against abortions in rape cases to the Thomson paper?

Tags: ethics, reference-request, life, abortion

Came here from [Christianity StackExchange](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/45311/22326)

"[A Defense of Abortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Defense_of_Abortion#The_Violinist)" (Thomson):

> You wake up in the morning and find yourself back to back in bed with
>   an unconscious violinist. A famous unconscious violinist. He has been
>   found to have a fatal kidney ailment, and the Society of Music Lovers
>   has canvassed all the available medical records and found that you
>   alone have the right blood type to help. They have therefore kidnapped
>   you, and last night the violinist's circulatory system was plugged
>   into yours, so that your kidneys can be used to extract poisons from
>   his blood as well as your own. [If he is unplugged from you now, he
>   will die; but] in nine months he will have recovered from his ailment,
>   and can safely be unplugged from you.

It is said later that:

> Critics of Thomson's argument generally grant the permissibility of
>   unplugging the violinist, but seek to block the inference that
>   abortion is permissible by arguing that there are morally relevant
>   differences between the violinist scenario and typical cases of
>   abortion.

But it is **unsourced**. :(

What are the morally relevant differences?

I **did** google responses to the Thomson paper, but they were either too wordy, too disorganized or incomprehensible. All I remember finding was this one paper about how unplugging is different from poisoning or something, but then it had too many words and now I can't find it.

Comment: What specifically are you hoping for in an answer here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wikipedia, which is the source of the quote, in another article also [lists the typical objections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_aspects_of_the_abortion_debate#The_bodily_rights_argument), with references, which arguably point out moral distinctions.

*The responsibility objection*: kidnapping makes the violinist scenario analogous only to abortion after rape, in most cases the intercourse was voluntarily, so the woman herself caused the baby to need her body.

*The stranger objection*: embryo is the woman's child, unlike the violinist.

*Let die objection*: abortion kills the embryo while unplugging the violinist only lets him die, so abortion is premeditated murder, but with unplugging death is a foreseeable but unintended consequence.

[Boonin argued](http://catdir.loc.gov/catdir/samples/cam033/2002022282.pdf) more recently (Thomson's paper is from 1971) that the above distinctions are either morally irrelevant, or do not apply to abortion in their moral aspect. Here is a critique of that [due to Beckwith](http://connection.ebscohost.com/c/book-reviews/20379899/defending-abortion-philosophically-review-david-boonins-defense-abortion).

Comment: The last objection is what I found on christianity stackexchange, but the grammar is wrong possibly. manythanks